# What is Hive Tablename maximum character limit?

Tags: hive, bigdata, hql, etl

Could not locate a suitable specification about the maximum character limit for a Hive Table.

I am developing an ETL process involving hive tables that have specified naming conventions with the format _ and the table names provided are quite larger than 30 byte (normal limit for pl/sql), a straight google search lands me with column name limit but no info on tablename.

Comment: Nit-picking: PL/SQL does not limit table names, because PL/SQL is just a _language_. The Oracle RDBMS limits table names to 30 single-byte characters (a legacy of the 1980's).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache Hive is Open Source. *In Source Code Veritas*.

With branch 2.1 for instance, the [Javadoc](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/index.html) and the Java source for "Metastore API" -- as well as the [Thrift message format](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.1/service-rpc/if/TCLIService.thrift) -- manage table names as generic Strings. No specific limit there.

But the Metastore service uses a RDBMS as back-end, and you can see that the standard [MySQL schema](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.1/metastore/scripts/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-2.1.0.mysql.sql) defines

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TBLS` (
...
 `TBL_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
...
```

Note that this 128-char-in-Latin-alphabet limit is the default when setting up Hive. A plain `ALTER TABLE` command afterwards would be sufficient to change that limit at database level, without having to recompile anything.

Answer (score 2):

Note hive table name seems to be larger than 128-char in newer hive versions.  See this link:
http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/Hive-naming-limits/m-p/80155#M2886

Answer (score 2):

- Table name is 256 characters
- Column name is 767 characters

[Information Source](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-naming-limits/td-p/80154)